# Why is the universal enveloping algebra generated by the image of ${\frak g}$ and $1$?

Tags: lie-algebras

Consider a Lie algebra ${\frak g}$, and denote its universal enveloping algebra with ${\cal U}({\frak g})$.

I've read, *e.g.* in these notes ([Link to pdf](http://relaunch.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/perrin/chap3.pdf)), Remark 3.1.3 at page 19, that the *two-sided ideal $\mathcal U_+$ is generated by the image of $\mathfrak g$ in $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$*, where here $\mathcal U_+$ denotes the subspace of $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$ of elements of degree more than $0$.

I don't understand how this is possible. I've read *e.g.* in the [relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra) that $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$ is generated by products of elements of $\mathfrak g$ of the form $x_1^{k_1}\cdots x_n^{k_n}$ (when $\mathfrak g$ is finite-dimensional). While nontrivial, I can understand this being the case. However, this sounds different than saying that $\mathcal U_+$ is "generated by the image of $\mathfrak g$ in the UEA". I understand the mapping $\mathfrak g\to\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$ as sending $g\in\mathfrak g$ into the corresponding rank-1 element in $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$. If $\mathfrak g$ is finite-dimensional, how can the image of this mapping *not* be also finite-dimensional? This seems at odds with the fact that $\mathcal U(\mathfrak g)$ is supposed to always be infinite-dimensional, as stated *e.g.* in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is generated by the image of $\frak g$ in $\mathcal U(\frak g)$ *as an algebra*, not as a vector space.

Comment: so is a set $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ defined to be a "generating set" for an algebra when the algebra can be written as linear combination of arbitrary products/powers of its elements?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.